# Apache CXF client unmarshal response

Tags: java, json, apache, cxf

How do I unmarshal a JSON response string into the correct object by using the Apache CXF rest client?

Below is my implementation which calls the rest end point. I'm using Apache CXF 2.6.14

Please not that the response status will tell me which object to unmarshal into.

```
public Object redeem(String client, String token) throws IOException {
    WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
    webClient.path(redeemPath, client);

    Response response = webClient.post(token);
    InputStream stream = (InputStream) response.getEntity();

    //unmarshal the value
    String value = IOUtils.toString(stream);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        //unmarshall into Error object and return
    } else {
        //unmarshall into Token object and return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

I'm running the project in a Tomee server.
Inside the Tomee lib folder the project is provided with a jettison lib.

> servers/apache-tomee-1.7.1-jaxrs/lib/jettison-1.3.4.jar

One can use the`JSONObject`which is inside the jettison lib in combination with JAXBContext to parse the JSON string being send back.

```
public Object redeem(String client, String token) throws Exception {
    WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
    webClient.path(redeemPath, client);

    Response response = webClient.post(token);
    InputStream stream = (InputStream) response.getEntity();

    //unmarshal the value
    String value = IOUtils.toString(stream);

    //use the json object from the jettison lib which is located in the Tomee lib folder.
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(value);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResourceError.class);
        XMLStreamReader reader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(jsonObject);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        ResourceError resourceError = (ResourceError) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        return resourceError;

    } else {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Token.class);
        XMLStreamReader reader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(jsonObject);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        Token token = (Token) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        return token;
    }
}
```